# Error loading the trace file in IDA PRO 7

Tags: reverse-engineering, ida

When i try to load a trace file, after saving it i get this message:

```
Error loading the trace file ... failed to unpack trace event #3
```

I run a trace, save it and then load it and i still get this message and only the first 2 entries in the stack trace.

What can that be and how to try and fix it?

The 3rd event is:

```
000075BC    msctf.dll:00007FF872E40000  Debug event: Library load: C:\windows\System32\msctf.dll    Debug event: Library load: C:\windows\System32\msctf.dll
```